¿Como utilizo las transiciones en angular?
Estoy iniciando con las transiciones en angular, antes utilizaba barbaj js para hacer transiciones entre vistas, pero veo q no se puede usar barba js por q angular ya tiene su propio modulo de transiciones entre rutas, me gustaria saber como puedo hacer esta trancision entre rutas en angular
( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2N8Xrsg2y4&t=8s )
ya hice la configuracion para q las animaciones funcionen, no se es como hacer especificamente esa trancicion del video
animation.ts
import { animate, animateChild, group, query, style, transition, trigger } from "@angular/animations";

export const slideInAnimation =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('buttonsPage => cardsPage', [
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%',
          padding: '40px'
        })
      ]),
      query(':enter', [
        style({ left: '-100%' })
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':leave', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('300ms 2s ease-out', style({ left: '100%' }))
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
          animate('300ms 2s ease-out', style({ left: '0%' }))
        ], { optional: true }),
      ]),
    ]),
    transition('cardsPage => buttonsPage', [
        style({ position: 'relative' }),
        query(':enter, :leave', [
          style({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            width: '100%',
            padding: '40px'
          })
        ]),
        query(':enter', [
          style({ right: '-100%' })
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':leave', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
        group([
          query(':leave', [
            animate('300ms 2s ease-out', style({ right: '100%' }))
          ], { optional: true }),
          query(':enter', [
            animate('300ms 2s ease-out', style({ right: '0%' }))
          ], { optional: true }),
        ]),
      ]),

  ]);

app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AccordionsComponent } from './components/accordions/accordions.component';
import { ButtonsComponent } from './components/buttons/buttons.component';
import { CardsComponent } from './components/cards/cards.component';
import { FormsComponent } from './components/forms/forms.component';
import { LoadersComponent } from './components/loaders/loaders.component';
import { NavbarsComponent } from './components/navbars/navbars.component';

const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: 'buttons', component: ButtonsComponent, data: {animation: 'buttonsPage'} },
  { path: 'cards', component: CardsComponent, data: {animation: 'cardsPage'} },
  { path: 'forms', component: FormsComponent},
  { path: 'loaders', component: LoadersComponent },
  { path: 'accordions', component: AccordionsComponent },
  { path: 'navbars', component: NavbarsComponent },

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/sidebar', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: ButtonsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

